# undefined is not a function (near '...ImagePicker.showImagePicker...')

Tags: javascript, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fWfg.png)
I've installed react-native-image-picker successfully, for a fresh react native app, linked it and given right permissions via the info.plist file to access camera, photos etc...

When attempting to openGallery() i get the following warning and no image library opens:
TypeError;undefined is not a function (near '...ImagePicker.showImagePicker...')

```
imagePickerHandler = () => {
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    Crop.openCropper({
      path: response.uri,
      includeBase64: true,
      width: 800,
      height: 340,
      cropperStatusBarColor: theme.colors.gary1,
      cropperActiveWidgetColor: theme.colors.primary,
      cropperToolbarColor: theme.colors.black,
      cropperToolbarWidgetColor: theme.colors.white,
    }).then(image => {
      this.setState({
        image: image.data,
        image_extension:
          image.path.split('.')[image.path.split('.').length - 1],
      });
    });
  }
});
```

};

enter code here

Comment: The error tells you specifically in which line the error occurred. You haven't provided line numbers in the codeblock, so please tell us exactly which function call failed.

Answer (score 1):

try making a named export

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1528

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker' fixed it
```

Comment: I use                                                                                                                                    
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import * as Crop from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';  i'm still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

error comes from `Crop.openCropper`
change it to `Crop.openPicker`

```
Crop.openPicker({
      path: response.uri,
      includeBase64: true,
      width: 800,
      height: 340,
      cropping: true,
      cropperStatusBarColor: theme.colors.gary1,
      cropperActiveWidgetColor: theme.colors.primary,
      cropperToolbarColor: theme.colors.black,
      cropperToolbarWidgetColor: theme.colors.white,
    })
```